# How can I terminate a secondary thread waiting for an object

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I created a secondary thread using `_beginthreadex`. When the process wants to stop. it has to terminate both threads.  The issue is the secondary thread is waiting on some handle (using `WaitForSingleObject`) and the main thread wants to terminate secondary one.

How can main thread notify the second thread to stop with `WaitForSingleObject` and then terminate?

Answer (score 16):

Add new event which is used to stop the thread:

```
HANDLE hStopEvent;
hStopEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
```

To stop another thread:

```
SetEvent(hStopEvent);    // ask thread to stop
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);   // wait when thread stops
```

In the thread code, replace `WaitForSingleObject` with `WaitForMultipleObjects`. Wait for exitsting event + `hStopEvent`. When `hStopEvent` is signaled, exit the thread function.

```
HANDLE hEvents[2];
hEvents[0] = <your existing event>;
hEvents[1] = hStopEvent;

for(;;)      // event handling loop
{
    DWORD dw = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);

    if ( dw == WAIT_OBJECT_0 )
    {
         // your current event handling code goes here
         // ...
    }
    else if ( dw == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 )
    {
        // stop event is set, exit the loop and thread function
        break;
    }
}
```